# Ionic 3 Alert; calling present() not working after calling dismiss()

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a network detection feature in my Ionic app. The goal is to prevent a user from interacting if there is no network.

Code is as below in page component:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
this.alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'No Network!',
      subTitle: 'Please Connect to Internet to Continue',
      enableBackdropDismiss: false
    });

    if(this.networkCheck.checkNetworkType() === 'none' || this.networkCheck.checkNetworkType() === 'unknown'){
      this.alert.present();
    }
this.networkSubscription = this.networkCheck.onStatusChange().subscribe(
      data => {
          console.debug(data);

          if(data.type === 'offline'){
              this.alert.present();
              this.toast.show(data.type);
          }
          else if(data.type === 'online'){
              this.alert.dismiss();
              this.toast.show(data.type);
          }
      })
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.networkSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

And in provider:

```
onStatusChange(){
    return this.network.onchange()
  }
```

The problem is while the Toast is showing for all status changes, the alert pop-up is showing only for the first time when the network is disconnected. After it gets dismissed for the first time, it is not showing up again.

Can you please help me with this?I am guessing something with viewDismiss is the reason behind why this is happening, but I could not get a hold on this.

And also please let me know if there is a better way to handle this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this solution.

```
alert:any;
showAlert(){
  this.alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'No Network!',
    subTitle: 'Please Connect to Internet to Continue',
    enableBackdropDismiss: false
  });
  this.alert.present();
}
ionViewDidEnter() {


  if (this.networkCheck.checkNetworkType() === 'none' || this.networkCheck.checkNetworkType() === 'unknown') {
    this.showAlert();
  }
  this.networkSubscription = this.networkCheck.onStatusChange().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.debug(data);

      if (data.type === 'offline') {
        this.showAlert();
        this.toast.show(data.type);
      }
      else if (data.type === 'online') {
        this.alert && this.alert.dismiss();
        this.toast.show(data.type);
      }
    })
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.networkSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is an easy workaround. Just asking, why an alert cannot be displayed again after dismissing?

Comment: in your case alert was created only one time,  but subscribe method call every time when network is ONLINE/ OFFLINE

Comment: Yes. My point is that I created the alert once. But based on network changes it should be presented and dismissed multiple time. Does the dismiss() call destroy the created alert? It supposes not. Might it be a bug or issue with the build?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in `app.component.ts` file so it will work for all pages.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, Alert, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  networkWarningAlert: Alert = null;
  disconnectSubscription: Subscription = null;
  connectSubscription: Subscription = null;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
    public alert: AlertController,
    private network: Network) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.SubscribeNetworkAction();
    });
  }

  isConnected(): boolean {
    let conntype = this.network.type;
    return conntype && conntype !== 'unknown' && conntype !== 'none';
  }

  SubscribeNetworkAction() {

    if (!this.platform.is("cordova"))
      return;

    if (!this.isConnected() && !this.networkWarningAlert) {
      this.networkWarningAlert = this.alert.create({
        title: 'No network',
        message: 'Check your internet connection',
        enableBackdropDismiss: false,
        buttons: [{
          text: "Exit",
          handler: () => { this.platform.exitApp(); }
        }]
      })
      this.networkWarningAlert.present();
    }

    this.disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (!this.networkWarningAlert) {
        this.networkWarningAlert = this.alert.create({
          title: 'No network',
          message: 'Check your internet connection',
          enableBackdropDismiss: false,
          buttons: [{
            text: "Exit",
            handler: () => { this.platform.exitApp(); }
          }]
        })
        this.networkWarningAlert.present();
      }
    });

    this.connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.networkWarningAlert) {
        this.networkWarningAlert.dismiss();
        this.networkWarningAlert = null;
      }
      // this code is used for refresh current page.
      var currentStack = this.nav.getViews();
      this.nav.setRoot(currentStack[0].component);
      for (var i = 1; i < currentStack.length; i++) {
        this.nav.push(currentStack[i].component, currentStack[i].getNavParams());
      }
    });
  }

  UnSubscribeNetworkAction() {
    if (!this.platform.is("cordova"))
      return;

    if (this.disconnectSubscription) {
      this.disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.disconnectSubscription = null;
    }
    if (this.connectSubscription) {
      this.connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.connectSubscription = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I eventually wrote it in app.component.ts. But using onChange() is more useful in my case rather than using two different onConnect() and onDisconnect().

Comment: Ok. But you have asked for alert.

Comment: Yes. onChnage() can also trigger alert. As it is shown in the selected answer

Comment: You have multiple choices. You can select any one of them. If you don't like this answer then leave it or downvote it.